# Where do I add the FPS filter and scale filter to an ffmpeg command?

Tags: ffmpeg

I am using this command to convert a folder of mp4s to webp using ffmpeg:

```
for i in *.mp4; do ffmpeg -i "$i" "${i%.*}.webp"; done
```

I want to add in an FPS filter and scale filter.

```
-filter:v fps=fps=15

-vf scale=450:-1
```

When I add in these filters to the command, I get errors. What is the correct way to add the filters to the command above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join simple filters with a comma:

```
for i in *.mp4; do ffmpeg -i "$i" -vf "fps=15,scale=450:-1" "${i%.*}.webp"; done
```

See [FFmpeg Filters Documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html) for more info.